# Genesis Conditional Hooks Not working What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, wordpress, genesis

So I am trying to call the genesis_do_nav hook so its only on the front page and the homepage. For some reason it doesn't work unless I do

add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_nav' );

But that is going to execute the menu on the entry header globally which is exactly what I am trying to avoid. Any suggestions

```
 remove_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_nav' );
    add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'menu_only_on_homepage' );

    function menu_only_on_homepage() {

        if( is_home() && is_front_page() ){
                genesis_do_nav();
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Two Ideas I would like you to try:

A. **First Issue I see is with your condition** i.e. `is_home() && is_front_page()` I think this condition will never be true as both are different pages. So maybe you wanted to have it `is_home() || is_front_page()`

B. **Try Re Arranging the code**, Try arranging your conditional in different order so that you have condition before you add the hook i.e.

```
    if(is_home() || is_front_page() ){
        add_action( 'genesis_entry_header', 'genesis_do_nav' );
        }
```

See if it helps in your situation please note code is untested as I wrote here so first test it on dev environment before trying on live so you could easily fix any typos or syntax errors.